# Podman - how do I state container port and host port?

Tags: localhost, port, podman

My first day with Podman. I am trying

```
sudo podman run -it solrX
```

I get Solr running fine but I cannot reach Solr default port on localhost:8983. I google more and try

```
sudo podman run -it solrX -p 8983:8983
```

to use 8983 both as container port and host port but it doesn't work. How do I do this? Any idea?

Comment: You need to place arguments to `podman` before your image name: `podman run -it -p 8983:8983 solrX`

Comment: See the [`podman-run` man page](https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-run.1.html) for details.